# Set $scope variable inside Angular Service

Tags: angularjs, service, angularjs-scope, angular-services, angular-controller

I have this Service in AngularJS:

```
this.getProductsSiteService = function(idSite) 
{
    return $http.get(BASE_URL + 'obtener/productos/sitio/'+idSite);
}
```

It works fine. I use the method below for consuming the service:

```
$scope.getProducts = function()
{
    auth.getSiteInfo().then(function(resp)
    {
        auth.getProductsSiteService(resp.data.idSite).then(function(response)
        {
            var json = angular.fromJson(response.data.Respuesta);
            $scope.products = json.Table;
        });
    });
};
```

This code works fine, I display the data of the `$scope.products` in the HTML temnplate with the `ng-repeat` directive, but I have this problem.
When I want to use `$scope.products` in other method of the same controller it is always empty. I call the `$scope.getProducts()` method and after that I use `console.log($scope.products)` and it is always `[]`.
I made a test I think it is because the `$scope.products` is inside of the Service, which uses `.then` to resolve the promise.

Anybody knows how to solve that problem? I need to use `$scope.products` in other methods of the controller.

Comment: Probably you are trying to acess `$scope.products` before the promise resolved. You could return the promise in `$scope.getProducts` and use `then` to ensure `$scope.prodcuts` has data

Comment: where are you calling console.log($scope.products)? Just after the $scope.getProducts  call?

Comment: Yes, I think thats the problem, the promise hasn't resolve yet. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I am calling after the $scope.getProducts() call. Something like this: $scope.getProducts(); ... console.log($scope.products) @user449689

Comment: ok, so read @taguenizy comment, I think it's right

Answer (score 0):

Let the service handle getting the site info and storing that. Then let it handle getting the products, and store that. Then, just ask for the products from the controller(s). The method could return a promise so that asking for the products works asynchronously when the products haven't been requested yet.

So something like:

```
   this.getProductsSiteService = function() {
      if (products) return $q.when(products);
      //do your http request here based on previously stored site id
      return $http.get(BASE_URL + 'obtener/productos/sitio/'+idSite).then(
         function(response) {
            var json = angular.fromJson(response.data.Respuesta);
            products = json.TABLE;
            return products;
         }
      )

   }
```